# Looking for JSON parsing library

Tags: json, angular, parsing

Is there a Javascript JSON parsing library out there that will parse a string like this?

```
‘{ param: “value” }’
```

I know that JSON.parse(‘{ param: “value” }’) won’t. Because there are no quotes around param, it throws an error:

```
Unexpected token p in JSON at position 2
```

But I can create Javascript objects with the standard JSON format without quotes around the property names:

```
const o = { param: ‘value’ };
```

So I don’t see why a string like ‘{ param: “value” }’ wouldn’t be parsable. JSON.parse(…) won’t do it, but are there other JSON parsing libraries that will?

I’m programming in Angular 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the fancy quotes in your question are a mistake, and that your real string looks like this:

```
{ param: "value" }
```

You can parse it using `eval`:

```
result = eval("(" + str + ")");
```

(If the fancy quotes are really there, you'll probably be tempted to replace them with `replace` or similar, but beware that doing so will also replace them *inside* strings.)

Live Example:

```js
const str = '{ param: "value" }';
const result = eval("(" + str + ")");
console.log(`result.param = ${result.param}`);
```

**WARNING:** Using `eval` in this way allows the supplier of the string to run arbitrary code within your code. So:

- Never use `eval` on a string from User A in User B's session; doing so allows User A to run arbitrary code in User B's browser — a **very** bad idea.
- Never use `eval` on a string supplied from a user on your server (because then your server is basically User B :-) )